# R import multiple files and perform complex function on them

Tags: r, file

I have a series of files that when I read them and manipulate them individually I don't have have problem.

They are organised as follows:

## e.g.

```
chrY<-read.table('chrY.txt', sep ='', header=F)
head(chrY)
        V1
1 4.514563
2 4.543689
3 4.553398
4 4.533981
5 4.495146
6 4.514563
```

I need to convert each of the values to numeric:

And so I try this for a list of chromosome files:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="chr*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i], sep ='', header=F))
> temp
[1] "chr17.txt" "chr18.txt"
[3] "chr19.txt" "chr1.txt" 
[5] "chr6.txt"  "chrY.txt"
```

Conversion to numerics:

```
for(i in temp){
  temp[i]<-as.numeric(temp[i])
}
```

I wanted to plot over the average of all the files and plot over them,

Plotting one imported file is fine:

```
plot(chrY.txt[,1])
```

my attempt at plotting the average values between all of them as follows:

```
for(i in length(temp)-1){ #index -1 such that iteration is not out of range
 x<-(temp[i][,1]+temp[i+1][,1])/length(temp)
}
plot(x)
```

however for the averaging-process I get the following error:

> Error in temp[i][, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Is there a faster way of doing this than a for loop in R? This is a practice run and I will be potentially importing a lot of files to average over

Comment: you have `length(temp)-1` and it is just a single value, may be you need `seq(length(temp)-1)`  Second problem in the last code is the `temp` is a `vector` of object names, you have to read it (as you did in the first block of code) and then do the summartion

Comment: Thanks @akrun tried it with the 'seq()' included but got the same error: could you be clearer with the second half of your instructions? as far as I can see the first block of code is accessing the vector the same way as the second block...

Comment: u need to read it `read.table(temp[i], sep ='', header=F)`

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you were referring to the numeric conversion: I tried the following:


> for(i in temp){
+   assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i], sep ='', header=F))
+   temp[i]<-as.numeric(temp[i])
+   x<-(temp[i][,1]+temp[i+1][,1])/length(temp)
+ }
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory

Comment: Note the error: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory

Comment: Try `temp <- list.files(pattern="chr*.txt"); lst <- lapply(temp, read.table, header=FALSE); Reduce('+', lst)/length(lst)`

Comment: It worked! thanks so much- if you post the following code as an answer I'll upvote it for you:
temp <- list.files(pattern="*average_aligned.w1.delta_20000_20000.txt"); temp <- lapply(temp, read.table, header=FALSE); Reduce('+', temp)/length(temp)

for(i in temp){
  assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i], sep ='', header=F))
  temp[i]<-as.numeric(temp[i])
  x<-(temp[i][,1]+temp[i+1][,1])/length(temp)
}

Comment: The problem seems like solved but anyway your original code had a mistake causing the dimension error. At the last loop, temp[i+1] would be greater then the length of temp when i is equal to the last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can read the files in a `list` and then use `Reduce` with `+` and divide by the `length` of the `list` to get the `mean` value

```
temp <- list.files(pattern="chr*.txt")
lst <- lapply(temp, read.table, header=FALSE)
Reduce('+', lst)/length(lst)
```